# Template function in C# - Return Type?

Tags: c#, templates, function-templates

It seems that c# does not support c++ like templates. For example

```
template <class myType>
myType GetMax (myType a, myType b) {
 return (a>b?a:b);
}
```

I want my function to have return type based on its parameters, how can i achieve this in c#? How to use templates in C#

**EDIT:** Can i use object and getType for the almost same purpose?

Comment: I don't see how you'd use GetType to accomplish the same thing, no. And you don't want an API returning object unless you're happy for the caller to have to cast all over the place.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The closest to C++ templates in C# is generics - but they're not *very* close. In particular, you can't use operators like `>` between generic type values, because the compiler doesn't know about them (and you can't constrain types based on operators). On the other hand, you can write:

```
public T GetMax<T>(T lhs, T rhs)
{
    return Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(lhs, rhs) > 0 ? lhs : rhs;
}
```

or

```
public T GetMax<T>(T lhs, T rhs) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    return lhs.CompareTo(rhs) > 0 ? lhs : rhs;
}
```

Note that the first of these is null-safe; the second isn't.

A full description of generics is well beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer; [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx) has some information, or consult your favourite C# book.

Comment: I've heard C# in depth has some good explanations of generics :)

Comment: The function i given was just a sample, What about functions other than comparison?

Comment: @Life2HO: Well, what function do you want? Is it an instance method which is specified in an interface? If so, you're fine.

Answer (score 9):

Generics in C# are not as powerful as templates in C++. What you want to do does not work in C#.

A hack/workaround for your situation is

```
public T GetMax<T>(T a, T b) where T: IComparable {
    if(a.CompareTo(b) > 0) {
        return a;
    }
    return b;
}
```

Comment: The function i given was just a sample, What about functions other than comparison?

Comment: @LifeH2O: It depends - is it specified in an interface? If so, you can constrain the generic type to implement the interface (or derive from a given base class, etc).

Comment: As a C++ developer you may find yourself disappointed with C#'s generics. But they are still useful in many scenarios, and worth learning.

Answer (score 5):

Your code would become something like this:

```
public T GetMax<T>(T a, T b) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    return a.CompareTo(b) > 0 ? a : b;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to have a look at [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx). Syntax:

```
public T GetMax<T>(T a, T b) {
    return (a>b?a:b);
}
```

**UPDATE** because of some comments... I just wanted to provide a **very quick** overview. Yeah I guess it doesn't compile or execute properly. But this is the basic idea on how this would look like. You'll find more complete replies on this topic - meanwhile.

Execution Syntax:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 10;
int result = GetMax(a, b);
```

Hope this helps,

Regards,
Thomas

Comment: I was about to say the same but that won't compile because of the line 'return (a>b?a:b);'  He will need an interface constraint or something...

Comment: You cannot compare a and b in this way, as the compiler has no idea what T is. What if the type T does not support comparison?

Answer (score 3):

You use Generics in C# to get template like functionality.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(VS.80).aspx

```
public class MyType<T>
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generics!

```
class MyClass<T> where T : IEnumerable (any parent class here!)
{
   T myGeneric {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You mean some thing like this

```
   public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectIfNotNull<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
   {
       if (source == null) return null;
       return source.Select(selector);
   }
```